# Unexplained async/await problem with Azure Storage Table access - is it OK to solve with ConfigureAwait(false)? Probably NOT

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, async-await, azure-table-storage

I'm in the third month of working on a new ASP.NET Framework WebApi app that is deployed to Azure.

I don't need to persist all that much data, but the data I do persist is in Azure Storage Tables.

About a week ago after weeks of no problems, I started running into trouble with async/await synchronization, seemingly out of the blue.  I was able to localize that problem to awaited asyncronous execution of access to Azure Storage Tables.  Here is a very simplified schematic of how my app works:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Hosting;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

public class DummyController : ApiController
{
    public async Task Post()
    {
        string payloadDescribingWork = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();  // Await here - request is disposed before async task queued.

        // Service that hooks by posting to me needs a 204 response immediately,
        // which is why I queue a background work item for the real work.
        // Background work item will never take longer than 30 seconds,
        // but caller will time out if I don't respond 
        HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async cancellationToken =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(3000, cancellationToken); // Simulate some work based on the payload above

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("MyConnectionString");
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("MyTableName");
            table.CreateIfNotExists();

            // Sometimes but not always, this next awaitable async insert operation will NEVER return
            // In that case the background work item will never complete and will only
            // ever go away when IIS cycles the thread pool.
            // However, if you look at the table with a table explorer, the row actually WAS successfully
            // inserted, even when this operation hangs.
            TableResult noConfigureAwaitResult = 
                await table.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.Insert(new TableEntity
                {
                    PartitionKey = "MyPartitionKey",
                    RowKey = "MyRowKey"
                }), cancellationToken);

            // The following awaitable async insert operation wrapped with "ConfigureAwait(false)"
            // will always return and always succeed.
            TableResult configureAwaitFalseResult = 
                await table.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.Insert(new TableEntity
                {
                    PartitionKey = "MyOtherPartitionKey",
                    RowKey = "MyOtherRowKey"
                }), cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        });

        // 204 response will be issued right away here by the web api framework.
    }
}
```

To reiterate what is in the comments of the snippet, sometimes but not always the access to the storage table using the `CloudTable.ExcecuteAsync()` method will simply hang forever, suggesting a deadlock, but if I append `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to the call, it always works fine.

The problem is I don't understand WHY.  It feels good to get my code working of course, but this may be masking a deeper problem.

So to the questions:

1. Given that my actual queued background work is much more complicated, anyone wish to hazard a guess as to why the storage table access hangs sometimes when not wrapped with `.ConfigureAwait(false)`?  Please note that I have made every exhaustive audit through my application to ensure that I am using async/await consistently up and down the callstack.
2. Given that I am able to get my application to work just fine by wrapping all Azure Storage Access operations with `ConfigureAwait(false)`, does anyone have an argument as to why this might be a terrible solution over the long term?

Comment: _"is it OK?"_ -- well, you have an **unexplained problem**. So, no. It's not okay to "fix" the problem by sprinkling `ConfigureAwait(false)` fairy dust over it. First you need to **explain the problem**. Only once the problem is understood can you then proceed to a valid fix. `ConfigureAwait(false)` very well might be the correct fix; it's a common solution when dealing with sync context deadlocks, and in many cases is the _right_ solution. But when you don't know what the actual problem is? Nope...you can't just sweep it under the rug. You have to debug it before you fix it.

Comment: Yes thank you @PeterDuniho - I agree with you, and you said it more forcefully and helpfully than I did.  I'm just out of understanding after days of weeding through the code, and that is why I wrote this post.  I appreciate it.  To be honest, I guess I am also fishing for anyone who knows saying "Oh right this is a known issue with storage table access".

Comment: Deadlock can be tricky to find in a large code base, but with some patience you should be able to find it. You're looking for a _blocking_ call that is tying up your sync context, and which is waiting for some other awaited async result to finish. Focus on the blocking calls...they will generally be found in some transition between layers (i.e. where someone thought they could get away with only pushing the async up so far), but in any case, they usually stand out like a sore thumb. Good luck.

Comment: Do not use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in controller action methods. That's where the `SynchronizationContext` is needed.

Comment: Hi @PauloMorgado - thanks, but please note it is in a seperate worker thread that is not part of the controller action, inside the delegate passed to ```HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem```.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in a less-than-satisfactory way, I won't vote for it or mark it the answer.

Thanks to the comments on my initial question and subsequent research, I really didn't like the `.ConfigureAwait(false)` solution.

I have however combed through the code and have not found a deadlock, and believe that there may be a problem in the storage table code.  I should say that I am using an older version of the SDK from NuGet, and because of other dependencies in my code can't easily upgrade that, but perhaps when I can refactor for that upgrade the issue will go away.  However, for now, I have found a wrapper I can put around my storage table calls that do the trick of allowing my code to complete in all cases.  I'm still not exactly sure why, but I prefer not switching synchronization contexts.  Certainly there is a performance penalty here, but for now I'll take it.

Here is my wrapper:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

public static class CloudTableExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Hacked Save Wrapped Execute Async
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cloudTable">Cloud Table</param>
    /// <param name="tableOperation">Table Operation</param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">Cancellation Token</param>
    /// <returns>Result of underlying ExecuteAsync()</returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Rather than wrapping the call to ExecuteAsync() with .ConfigureAwait(false) and hence not using the current Synchronization Context,
    /// I am forcing the response to be followed with Task.Yield().  I may be able to stop use of this wrapper once I am able to advance
    /// to the newest release of the Azure Storage SDK.
    /// </remarks>
    public static async Task<TableResult> HackedSafeWrappedExecuteAsync(this CloudTable cloudTable, TableOperation tableOperation, CancellationToken? cancellationToken = null)
    {
        try
        {
            return await (cancellationToken == null ? cloudTable.ExecuteAsync(tableOperation) : cloudTable.ExecuteAsync(tableOperation, cancellationToken.Value));
        }
        finally
        {
            await Task.Yield();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Hacked Safe Wrapped Execute Batch Async
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cloudTable">Cloud Table</param>
    /// <param name="tableBatchOperation">Table Batch Operation</param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">Cancellation Token</param>
    /// <returns>Result of underlying ExecuteBatchAsync</returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Rather than wrapping the call to ExecuteBatchAsync() with .ConfigureAwait(false) and hence not using the current Synchronization Context,
    /// I am forcing the response to be followed with Task.Yield().  I may be able to stop use of this wrapper once I am able to advance
    /// to the newest release of the Azure Storage SDK.
    /// </remarks>
    public static async Task<IList<TableResult>> HackedSafeWrappedExecuteBatchAsync(this CloudTable cloudTable, TableBatchOperation tableBatchOperation, CancellationToken? cancellationToken = null)
    {
        try
        {
            return await (cancellationToken == null ? cloudTable.ExecuteBatchAsync(tableBatchOperation) : cloudTable.ExecuteBatchAsync(tableBatchOperation, cancellationToken.Value));
        }
        finally
        {
            await Task.Yield();
        }
    }
}
```